# Angular 2 custom html

Tags: javascript, angular, leaflet

I am using leaflet.js which is a native javascript library to render maps, markers etc. 
The marker feature of the marker works something like this:

```
let content:string = `
            <div class="icons">
                <a  class="route">28</a>
                <a  class="icon"><span class="stop"></span></a>
                <a  class="icon"><span class="coordinates"></span></a>
                <a  class="icon"><span class="expand"></span></a>
            </div>
        `;

        let options: any = {
            maxWidth: 500,
            className : 'infoPopup',
            closeOnClick: false,
            offset: [0, 0]
        }
        this.marker.bindPopup(content, options).openPopup();
```

This works ok, but i have no idea how to listen to click actions on the icons. I've tried with (click) but obviously its not working since its angular is not compiling it. I've tried which onclick="" but doesen't work so good since "this" is not available there. No idea what to try next.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks,
Radu